# can't create Amazon Sqs in Android but it create it in Java application

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I cannot create queue in Android but with same code it creates in java application.
What should I do?

Here is my code snippet:

```
AmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient( new BasicAWSCredentials( "access key", "secret key" ));
String Url = sqs.createQueue(new CreateQueueRequest(email)).getQueueUrl();
```

and here is my stack trace:

```
05-20 08:28:24.187: W/dalvikvm(1452): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a85ba8)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): Process: com.cloud.sensor, PID: 1452
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:377)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:228)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1004)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.createQueue(AmazonSQSClient.java:845)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.cloud.sensor.Register.register(Register.java:80)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.cloud.sensor.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:48)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-20 08:28:24.247: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the code snippet on the main thread. You need to run it in the background thread. One way to accomplish this is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).